# Getting Internal Server Error when loading a view in a mixed Angular & .Net MVC app

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an MCV controller method which can load a total of 3 separate views, two of which are error pages just containing some static html.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string c)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = new HG.EnterpriseTools.Types.CodeContainer();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c))
                return InvalidLink();
            model = HG.EnterpriseTools.CareNotifyCodeManager.ValidateCode(c);
            if (model.IsExpired)
            {
                return ExpiredLink();
            }
            if (!model.IsValid || model.PatientID == -1)
            {
                return InvalidLink();
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("fooController Index :: Error ::" + ex.Message);
        }

        return InvalidLink();            
    }
```

I have an Index.cshtml which only contains `<div ng-view></div>` and get's loaded in through the `RenderBody()` like any standard MVC page. Once the Index page loads I want all other routing to be handled by Angular using ngRoute. Here is a small example of what my routeProvider configuration.

```
careNotify.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'MainController',
        templateUrl: 'Views/splash.html'
    }).when('/login', {
        controller: 'loginController',
        templateUrl: 'Views/Account/login.html'
    })
});
```

Yet when the index page loads and successfully attempts to load the default route as expected it fails with a 500 error. If instead I try to change the `templateUrl` path to `../Views/splash.html` then I just get a 404. Any guidance? I'm still trying to wrap my head around mixing Angular and MVC with out needing to make a controller for each view and convert everything to .cshtml pages.

Comment: Can you show any message of the 500 error?

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen this is about the best I can do from my log file 2016-03-23 22:49:17,544 HG.Models.Helpers.Logger - Server Last Exception from Global.asax :: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Path '/HG.CareNotifyBridge/Views/splash.html' was not found.
   at System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use .Net MVC to only load index page and Angular for all other routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157239/use-net-mvc-to-only-load-index-page-and-angular-for-all-other-routes)

Comment: Using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) is actually only causing more problems for me. I will edit the question to reduce confussion.